# Как упростить и сделать без Object.keys?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли данный код как-то упростить и оптимизировать?

```
     const k = Object.keys(this.state.personalData).map(item => {
                  return getValidationState(item, 
                  this.state.personalData[`${item}`]);
       });


      const isFormInvalid = k.some(
        state => state === 'error'
    );
```

Comment: ну как минимум можно выкинуть промежуточную переменную k и присобачить some сразу к map

Comment: `\`${item}\``- не нужно, хватит просто `item`. Чем не нравится `keys`?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` это что-то по типу

```
Object.prototype._keys= function () {
 var arr = [];
 for(var i in this){
   if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)) arr.push(i)
 }
 return arr;
}
```

В итоге Вы можете заменить `Object.keys` на `for in`, но в таком случае Вы лишитесь "функционального" стиля